# Loop through each file in directory and write output to text

Tags: c#, xml

I have around 15,000 XML files in a folder, an example of a XML filename is; 000010000.img.xml

Each XML file contains specific information I need in a single text file.

Each XML file has the exact same structure aside from the information presented.

Here is what I want to focus in on (within the XML file)

```
<imgdir name="000010000.img">
   <imgdir name="info">
      <int name="version" value="10" />
      <int name="cloud" value="0" />
      <int name="town" value="0" />
      <float name="mobRate" value="1.0" />
      <string name="bgm" value="Bgm34/MapleLeaf" />
      <int name="returnMap" value="10000" />
      <string name="mapDesc" value="" />
      <int name="hideMinimap" value="0" />
      <int name="forcedReturn" value="999999999" />
      <int name="moveLimit" value="0" />
      <string name="mapMark" value="MushroomVillage" />
      <int name="swim" value="0" />
      <int name="fieldLimit" value="8260" />
      <int name="VRTop" value="-892" />
      <int name="VRLeft" value="-1064" />
      <int name="VRBottom" value="915" />
      <int name="VRRight" value="1334" />
      <int name="fly" value="0" />
      <int name="noMapCmd" value="0" />
      <string name="onFirstUserEnter" value="" />
      <string name="onUserEnter" value="go10000" />
      <int name="standAlone" value="0" />
      <int name="partyStandAlone" value="0" />
      <string name="fieldScript" value="" />
   </imgdir>

   </imgdir>
   <imgdir name="portal">
      <imgdir name="0">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-389" />
         <int name="y" value="183" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="1">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-416" />
         <int name="y" value="185" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="2">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-450" />
         <int name="y" value="183" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="3">
         <string name="pn" value="out00" />
         <int name="pt" value="2" />
         <int name="x" value="1080" />
         <int name="y" value="541" />
         <int name="tm" value="20000" />
         <string name="tn" value="in00" />
         <string name="script" value="" />
         <int name="hideTooltip" value="0" />
         <int name="onlyOnce" value="0" />
         <int name="delay" value="0" />
      </imgdir>
   </imgdir>
```

A batch file does not work; as you can see in my other thread: [Batch script not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651038/batch-script-not-working?noredirect=1#comment34501855_22651038)

I need a C# application to open each XML file, grab specific information (that I will specify below), write that information into a single text file, and rinse and repeat till every XML file has been read.

Using the XML file snippet/actual XML file information posted above, here is how I need the text file text structure to be;

```
[10000]
total=4
sp 0 -389 183 999999999
sp 0 -416 185 999999999
sp 0 -450 183 999999999
out00 2 1080 541 20000
```

I just cannot wrap my head around on how to do this in a c# console application.

I am asking for help, anything is appreciated!

Comment: You're probably looking for the `Directory.GetFiles` method as seen at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx. If you're dealing with multiple levels of directories, you'll probably have to get a list of folders within the target and recursively call your processing function on each of those.

Comment: I am not dealing with multiple levels of directories, they are all in one folder.

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` gets you all files in a specific directory - you'll need that, trust him ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty program I wrote up. I had to add a root to your XML file for it to play nice-nice with the program. I hope this helps!

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5 {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            string test = getValuesOneFile("xmltest.xml");

            Console.WriteLine(test);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static string getValuesOneFile(string fileName) {

            string finalString = "";

            XElement xmlDocument = XElement.Load((fileName));

            XElement infoImgDir = GetImgDir(xmlDocument, "info");

            finalString += "[" + GetInt(infoImgDir, "returnMap") + "]\n";

            finalString += "total=" + GetChildrenCount(GetImgDir(xmlDocument,"portal")) + "\n";

            IEnumerable<XElement> portals = GetImgDir(xmlDocument, "portal").Elements();

            foreach (XElement currentPortal in portals) {
                finalString += GetString(currentPortal, "pn") + " ";
                finalString += GetInt(currentPortal, "pt") + " ";
                finalString += GetInt(currentPortal, "x") + " ";
                finalString += GetInt(currentPortal, "y") + " ";
                finalString += GetInt(currentPortal, "tm") + "\n";
            }

            return finalString;
        }

        public static XElement GetImgDir(XElement file, string imgDirName) {
            return file.Descendants("imgdir").FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == imgDirName);

        }

        public static int GetInt(XElement data, string attribName) {
            var element = data.Descendants("int").FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == attribName);

            if (element == null)
                return 0;

            var value = (int?)element.Attribute("value");

            if (value == null)
                return 0;

            return value.Value;
        }

        public static string GetString(XElement data, string attribName) {
            var element = data.Descendants("string").FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == attribName);

            if (element == null)
                return "";

            var value = (string)element.Attribute("value");

            if (value == null)
                return "";

            return value;
        }

        public static int GetChildrenCount(XElement data) {
            return data.Elements().Count();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. I will just add in the loop to read all xmls, and save it to a .txt

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"SomeWhere");
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    // Grab information from the lines and store it in result
    // by using result.Add(...) or result.AddRange(...)
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"AlsoSomewhere", result);
```

Comment: But they are XML files? Also what you mean store it in importantLines, how would I store it? But these are XML files, my code wouldn't work if you put the files into a string?

Comment: XML files are plain text too, right? So you can just open each file (which is done by File.ReadAllLines) and just process the information in the file (which has to be done where the comment stands). There you just append the lines you want in the "complete" text file.

Comment: Ya but the code I posted is XELEMENT, i wouldn't know how to do this if it is not an xml file...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your problem. You can open the example file with a simple text editor. In the same way you use the method `File.ReadAllLines` to read all lines in the file. Afterwards you can process each line as you wish.

Comment: Ah - guess I got your problem. You can use `XElement.Load` to create an instance of the `XElement class` from file. So instead of `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);` just use `XElement element = XElement.Load(file);` and afterwards process it with your method.

Comment: `GetFiles` takes in a search pattern such as "*.xml" if you only want to pull in files with that extension. To test whether it's actually an XML file... there's probably a more elegant way, but the easiest way is to put it in a try/catch block. If it fails with an exception that it's not a valid XML file, just move on to the next file, probably logging it for the user in case they thought that the file was valid (for example, it might have been hand-built and include restricted characters).

Comment: I get errors such as; Data at the root level is invalid.

Comment: @user3457618: That's generally indicative that you have bad XML. For example in the file you have above, you have more than one root element (notice how you close `<imgdir>` twice after the Info element and before Portal).